# Animating a TextView each time it is changed

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, textview

I have a button which basically changes the TextView every time it is clicked. Is it possible to associate an animation with this? I have looked at things such as a 3D flip but they seem a little too advanced for me. Any simpler suggestions?

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_random_text);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView.setText(getNextRandomCuisine());
     }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at the Android webPage. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html
the class AnimationUtils helps you to load and Animation Pattern from your xml folder, you can for example make a "fadein" animation, you should dafür create an xml datei, name it for example "fadein.xml" it should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<alpha
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" >
</alpha>
```

with this you are just telling your android device, that this animation should variates the alpha value (also the transparence) of your view, from 0 to 1, making  your view visible, the "duration" parameter is just how any milliseconds will take to execute this animation.